# C#: Unable to read file contents

Tags: c#, c#-3.0, fileinputstream

I am trying to read the contents of a '.tmp' file provided as a command line argument in C#, but it either doesn't read the data or there might be some other issue:
    PFB the code snippet in C# :

```
 StreamReader  inpFile2 = new StreamReader(args[1]);
 string line;
 while ((line = inpFile2.ReadLine()) != null) {
     Console.WriteLine(line);
 }
```

where args[1] is a.tmp file with the below contents:

```
Name: <<NAME>>  (<<COURSE>>)
    ID: <<ID>>
    Total: <<TOTAL>>/100    Subtotal: <<SUBTOTAL>>      Total deductions: <<LATEDEDUCTION>>

Time due: <<DUE>>
Submitted: <<SUBMITTED>>
Late minutes: <<MINUTESLATE>>
Late deduction: <<LATEDEDUCTION>>

Problem 1: <<P1>>/35
<<P1COMMENTS>>

Problem 2: <<P2>>/65
<<P2COMMENTS>>
```

It does not display anything.Can you point out what the problem is?I am new to C-sharp.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code? When debugging, does line contain anything?  This code works fine for me.

Comment: Are you sure args[1] is being populated properly? You can add a breakpoint and see what the contents of that variable is.

Comment: What do you mean by stepping through the code @Web

Comment: Like Waragi said, put a breakpoint and see the contents of variables.  You can continue to step line by line by hitting F10 in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just open a file with its name. You need its path too. Probably the current working directory.

Try changing

```
StreamReader  inpFile2 = new StreamReader(args[1]);
```

To

```
var fileName = args[1];
var path = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, fileName);
StreamReader  inpFile2 = new StreamReader(path);
```